# How to see apps which were granted for root access in cyanogenmod or LOS?

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access

It's not a problem to set root access in cyannogenmod.
But how to see which apps have root privileges?

Answer (score 5):

I've found this in: Settings->Privacy->Privacy Guard->Advanced->Swipe right to the last Tab 'ROOT ACCESS'.

Comment: Good find – and thanks for sharing! I was already asking myself what I've missed, and never got the idea to look for it in "advanced". Well hidden it is!